# Is it possible to create a send packets to client using its ip/host from a third party program?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, ip, port

I have a simple server client (TCP/UDP socket) program. I know that the server bind itself to host+port, and a connecting client get a (usually random) port. Let's call client port.

Is it possible to create a third party program which can connect to the client using its client port.

(I know in this case there is a problem to identify the packets, but It seems theoretically should work, but I don't know how.)

Ex.:

1. Server: 123.456.789.159:80
2. Client, which is running on 1.2.3.4 connect to server (123.456.789.159:80) and got a port: 60789. (Now the server sends data to 1.2.3.4:60789)
3. I have a third party program on a third machine. Can it sends packets to client sending to 1.2.3.4:60789?

Any example in any language also would help.

Comment: It's possible if client side has active port `60789` and the client's OS is listening incoming TCP connections on that port ... and if your *third party program* is able to create socket

Comment: Remember that UDP is connectionless, which means you can send a packet to an UDP "client" *or* "server" from anywhere really. It's not really possible with TCP, unless you want to *spoof* the packets (which is considered a bad thing to do).

Answer (score 1):

You can't 'reuse' the client's TCP port. You'd have to establish a socket connection to the client which isn't possible when the port isn't listening. Forged TCP data segments will get dropped as the don't belong to an active socket.

With UDP, this is possible as there's no connection handshake and the UDP socket has only a few states.